# Accessing the list while being sorted

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-internals

Can I access a list while it is being sorted in the `list.sort()`

```
b = ['b', 'e', 'f', 'd', 'c', 'g', 'a']
f = 'check this'

def m(i):
    print i, b, f
    return None

b.sort(key=m)
print b
```

this returns

```
b [] check this
e [] check this
f [] check this
d [] check this
c [] check this
g [] check this
a [] check this
```

Note that individual items of list `b` is sent to function `m`. But at `m` the list `b` is empty, however it can see the variable `f`, which has same scope as list `b`. Why does function `m` print `b` as `[]`?

Comment: `m` can indeed see the list `b` (otherwise an error would be raised), only that it is empty as soon as you call `sort` on it.

Comment: thats right, I changed the question now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L2211) (of CPython, maybe different behaviour for other implementations) the strange output of your script becomes obvious:

```c
/* The list is temporarily made empty, so that mutations performed
 * by comparison functions can't affect the slice of memory we're
 * sorting (allowing mutations during sorting is a core-dump
 * factory, since ob_item may change).
 */
saved_ob_size = Py_SIZE(self);
saved_ob_item = self->ob_item;
saved_allocated = self->allocated;
Py_SET_SIZE(self, 0);
```

The comment says it all: When you begin sorting, the list is emptied. Well, it is "empty" in the eye of an external observer.

I quite like the term "core-dump factory".

---

Compare also:

```
b = ['b','e','f','d','c','g','a']
f = 'check this'


def m(i):
    print i, b, f
    return None

b = sorted(b, key= m)
print b
```

Comment: There is also a specific [mention in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) of this behavior. See note 10, under Mutable Sequence Types.

Answer (score 4):

This is something you can't rely on in general - not just for lists - unless the documentation for the method you're using *explicitly* says otherwise. Accessing an object in an intermediate state - ie, after some iteration has been started, but before it has been finished - is a problem that concurrent code runs into a lot. You've found a rare non-concurrent case of it, but the advice is the same: avoid this situation. The intermediate state is not guaranteed to be meaningful to you, and is not guaranteed to be a "valid" state according to the rules of that object (when it tends to be called an "inconsistent" state).

Comment: +1 from me. Mutability is the end of all programming. :-) State Monad FTW!

Comment: what if I want to do sort the list by calling a function that uses index of the item as a parameter. is there no way to do that, without copying the original list?

Comment: @nr.o Like posted in my answer: you can use `sorted` instead (which also creates a copy, so no real gain actually, but you don't have to copy it explicitly).

Comment: @nr.o: If you want to use the index, you'll be using `sorted(enumerate(l), key=whatever)` rather than calling `index`, because `index` is far slower and bug-prone when the list contains duplicates.