# python sort list, sorted() vs sort()

Tags: python, list

anybody can tell why sort() doesn't work below? thanks
- i test in python 2, and get erroer below

```
res = a.index(x)
ValueError: 1 is not in list
```

detailed codes:

```
a = [1, 3, 2, 5]

def f(y):
    print a

def fn(x):
    global a  # without `global`, you can still read variable `a` from outside
    print 'read a?'
    print a, type(a), id(a)
    res = a.index(x)
    return res

f(0)
a = sorted(a, key=fn)
print '----'
print a

print 'a.sort start'
a.sort(key=fn)  # a become [] ... no idea why!
print '----'
print a
```

Comment: `a.sort()` empties out `a` temporarily to re-insert sorted values. So when you use `a.sort(key=fn)` you are looking at an empty list in `fn` because you are already sorting that list. See [Python accessing the list while being sorted](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22678141)

Comment: @Felix Liu: Martijn Pieters commented a lot, but didn't point out where the ValueError comes from. It's in his comment about "`a.sort()` empties out `a` temporarily". As a result your function `fn` tries to find an index of an element while `a` is empty. Hence the ValueError.

Comment: @Martijn Peters: Your comments about the use of `key=function` are wrong. Felix Liu is using `a.index` which throws a ValueError.

Comment: @mkiever: ah, indeed, I somehow read that as `a.sort()`, not `a.index()`.

Comment: @mkiever: the `IndexError` comes from the fact that the list is empty. See [Python accessing the list while being sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22678141)

Comment: @mkiever: re-duped the post now.

Comment: @FelixLiu, ...transporting comments here (will delete later) re: your now-removed OpenCV question. It's not the lack of specificity in your request that was a problem (it's very clear what code you were asking us to write for you) -- but we aren't a code-writing-on-request service; it was failure to specify *a specific and narrow problem with your existing code* that made the question fatally flawed.